# CardView not clickable because of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cardview

I have cardviews in recyclerview

CardView not clikable if viewpager has adapter. So item in viewpager get over cardview. How fix this?

My CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">

    <android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="150%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%" />

    </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My item in ViewPager:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```